# How can I resolve the issue of taking lot of memory space for loading images in retina display devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, memory-profiling

I am developing an iPad paint application in which user can paint N number of images and have a gallery to export painted images to different social networks etc.Here the issue is that I am getting a lot of memory warnings (which eventually leads to crash)when I use iPad retina devices.I tried profiling and identified that the items like imageio_png_data,VM:CoreAnimation,VM: CG raster data are taking a lot of memory on comparing with the same in non retina devices.I understood that this is something related with image loading as I am loading images like PNG,JPG file formats in the app.

1.How can I resolve the problem of taking lot of memory space for loading images in retina display devices

2.How can I make the app avoiding huge consumption of memory for the terms like  imageio_png_data, VM:CoreAnimation,VM: CG raster data.

3.I got some information that PVR texture like images can be used for resolving memory related issues for images.Is it possible for me to integrate it in native iOS application.(I am also saving images at run time as it is a paint application.)

Answer (score 0):

You can compress image with low quality if this option is right for you.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.2); // 0.2 - quality
UIImage *lowQualityImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

If you have many image do not store they in array, use NSCache.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this method in UIImage category:

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
                transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
           drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

and resize yours UIImage to UIImageViews size for non retina  and to views size multiplied to 2 for retina.

Answer (score 0):

The images you are loading take about 4 times the memory when using retina (x2) images and 9 times the memory for (x3). The data when using formats such as png will need to de decompressed, copied and sent to the GPU which in some cases results in having 3 copies of image data in memory per image which is bad obviously. Still your iPad should have enough memory to load more textures then you can draw in real time.

From what you told us it is hard to know where your issue truly is but first thing you should make sure is when you load the images you should serialize the operation. That means you should load 1 texture, make sure all the image data has been cleaned from the loading (2 out of 3 copies), then start loading the next texture. I do not know what you use to load the texture but the good old "getting the raw RGBA data" should be near best in your case.

If this is not the case and you actually have too many textures loaded you came to the point you need to think about how to minimize the texture count or their resolution, you reached the device capability and there is not much more you can do. Also using texture atlas might help you a lot.

When it comes to texture loading and deleting you might consider reusing the texture, sending new data to it instead of deleting and creating a new texture. And for the image data itself you could load the images in some load time (could even be just the first time the application is ran) and then save the raw RGBA data to a new file. Using this approach will significantly decrease both your texture load time and memory footprint, the downside is you will use user disc space.